# Load Excel Combobox when the excel is opened

Tags: vba, excel

I have Combo box in Excel and I have following VBA code. But now working when the excel is opened.

```
Sub worksheet_activate()
mapping.clear
mapping.Additem "File to Table"
mapping.Additem "Table to File"
End Sub
```

Now , tell me how to load the combobox automatically when the excel is opened.

Comment: 1) Where is the code pasted? 2) What kind of Combo is that - ActiveX or Form Control? 3) Is this the 1st Sheet?

Comment: @Siddarth, Code pasted in VBA sheet1 page. It is not in form. It is in Excel sheet. Yes it is in  first sheet.

Comment: No I mean, is the combo an ActiveX Control or a form control. If it is an ActiveX Control and the name of the combobox is `mapping` then your code will work as expected provided macros are enabled

Comment: Is it possible for us to see a sample of your workbook?

Comment: @SiddharthRout : my sheet is in server. i can not share. May i know like, what is the default inbuilt function name to components when the excel is opened ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your question.

Comment: Could you explain why you have tagged this question with vb.net?

Comment: vb.net tag removed.. wrongly choosen when popup raised...

Comment: `worksheet_activate` does not fire when a workbook is opened, even if that sheet is the active sheet.  You can use `workbook_open` to call a sub to populate the combobox.

Comment: @TimWilliams : Even i have tried following code and opened the sheet but there is no values in Combobox. Pls help ?

Sub workbook_open()
mapping.Clear
mapping.AddItem "File to Table"
mapping.AddItem "Table to File"
End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked when I did like this. Do this in Worksheet macro.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
With Sheet1.mapping
.AddItem "File to Table"
.AddItem "Table to File"
End With
End Sub
```